# Что делает код int main(){[](){}();}

Tags: c++, c++11

На собеседовании задали вопрос - Что делает данный код?

```
int main(){[](){}();}
```

Comment: Хороший первый вопрос. Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Правильный ответ: ***ничего не делает***.

А означает он следующее:

```
int main()  // Функция main без аргументов.
{
    []    // Объявление лямбда-функции без списка захвата...
    ()    // ... с пустым списком аргументов ...
    {}    // ... и пустым телом, ...
    ();   // ... которая тут же вызывается.
}
```

Comment: Вторые скобки означают вызов?

Comment: @Ivan43 Да. Вторые круглые скобки означают вызов.

Comment: Да, это анонимная функция и вторые скобки означают ее вызов: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662688/parentheses-at-the-end-of-a-c11-lambda-expression

Answer (score 22):

Данная программа просто возвращает 0 в вызывающую программу. Находящийся в теле программы вызов лямбда-выражения  может быть проигнорирован, то есть для него не будет сгенерировано никакого объектного кода, так как это выражение не имеет побочных эффектов.

Поэтому программа не имеет смысла.

Comment: Кстати, да. В наплюсованном ответе ничего не сказано про возвращаемое значение. "Может быть проигнорирован" - кем или чем? Компилятором?

Comment: Смысл может быть хотя бы в проверке компилятора на `c++11`

Comment: @alexolut  Я думаю, что для этого не требуется писать отдельную программу.

Comment: Способы могут быть разные. Просто утверждение про отсутствие смысла это скорее мнение, чем факт.

Comment: @NickVolynkin § 3.6.1 Main function

A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

Comment: @NickVolynkin, т.е. 0 оно вернёт.

Comment: @MonahTuk речь о возвращаемом значении из лямбды, а не из `main`. Насчет генерации объектного кода тут вопрос, ибо без оптимизации код будет. Проверено на [godbolt](http://goo.gl/BdLTgZ)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Лямбда не имеет возвращаемого значения (`void`), `main` в соответствии со стандартом при отсутствии `return` вернёт ноль. Компилятор может проигнорировать, т.е. "выкинуть" код, не имеющий эффекта.

Comment: @kff какой пункт Стандарта говорит об возможности выкидывания кода лямбды?

Comment: @alexolut Объектный код не имеет никакого отношения к стандарту C. Главное - чтобы результат программы соответствовал результату, который был бы получен абстрактной машиной.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вот я прошу сноску на Стандарт.

Comment: @alexolut Какую сноску на стандарт? Стандарт говорит лишь о валидности конструкций языка C, а не о том, как компилятор может генерировать объектный код.

Comment: @alexolut Вот вам соответствующая цитата: "1.9 Program execution [intro.execution]
1 The semantic descriptions in this International Standard define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine. This International Standard places no requirement on the structure of conforming implementations. In particular, they need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below.5"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow спасибо. Более понятно, имхо, по сноске написано: `an actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no side effects affecting the observable behavior of the program are produced.`

Answer (score 16):

Как уже все ответили -- пустая лямбда.

А использоваться может в каком-нибудь configure, перед сборкой переносимого проекта для уточнения свойств системы при автоматической генерации, например, `configure.h`

Comment: Кстати, это единственный ответ, который указывает на реально возможное _практическое_ применение такого кода.

Answer (score 11):

Судя по всему объявляет пустую лямбда-функцию и выполняет ее.

Comment: Это и так понятно, можно подробнее?

Comment: А вторые `()` для чего?

Comment: @PavelParshin именно это меня и интересует

Comment: @Ivan43 я могу конечно ошибаться, но вторые скобки ее тут же выполняют