# Синтаксический разбор выражения для собеседования

Tags: c++, синтаксический-анализ, задание-на-собеседовании, expressions, выражение

```
int main() { return !0'0.*-+!!""; }
```

Что возвращает данная программа и почему?

Comment: а куда собеседуетесь?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/477156/456978

Comment: И что, у вас какие-то мысли есть? Какая-то конкретная часть непонятна?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11656/456978

Comment: я сегодня чувствую уже буду третью задачу на собеседование решать. Вот интересно, уже в гугл взяли или только в майкрософт? или это я кому то помогаю туда попасть:)

Comment: @ueber Тот вопрос видел, с автором не согласен.

Comment: так там другой вопрос.

Comment: ох, боюсь закроют вопрос... @ueber - хотите ответ - пишите куда собеседуетесь/собеседуете

Answer (score 2):

Происходит вот что:

```
int main() {

  return static_cast<int>(!0.0) * -+static_cast<int>(!!"");
}
```

`0'0.` - это число типа double, которое равно нулю. Символ `'` можно использовать для разделения разрядов числа (добавлено в C++14), он игнорируется компилятором (cм. [Floating point literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)).

Далее, к этому числу применяется логическое отрицание, что даёт **1**. Подробнее, про логическое отрицание над числом см. тут: [What happens when you logical not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833790/what-happens-when-you-logical-not-a-float).

Далее, `""` - пустая строка, к которой применяется операция двойного логического отрицания. И после приведения к int, получается **1**.

Затем, выполняются унарные операции `+` и `-` для получившейся единицы, что в результате даёт **-1**.

Ну и наконец, выполняется произведение первой **1** и второй **-1**, в результате получаем всё ту же **-1**.

Comment: теперь точно автор вопрос не ответит

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть: [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (*"Отвечайте на хорошо заданные вопросы"*), и [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (*"Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно"*).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat если вот это был хороший вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477156 то что не так здесь?

Comment: @zed Хмм. Как я понимаю: там спрашивают про ровно одну фичу языка. Готов поверить, что не очень широко известную. В случае с лямбдой, ты или знаешь что это, или не знаешь. А тут - вопрос про кучу отдельных маленьких фич. ТС мог бы хотя бы попробовать что-то сам решить. Ну хоть какими-то мыслями поделиться.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Нет, вопрос ровно из той же категории - написан набор бессмысленных символов (на первый взгляд), который как-то работает. И для новичка, разминировать такое выражение действительно сложно.

Comment: Наш "новичок" уже собеседования проходит. :/

Comment: *`"Далее, "" - пустая строка, к которой применяется операция..."`* -- точнее, операция применяется к указателю (`const char *`) на пустую строку, а затем, получившийся тип `bool` приводится к `int`